# Adding Values to a Column in FILTER() on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working with the following [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Q1y-0DtCYhm_nCt2-cSn64afi4XktnXy08B3yPhzTM/edit?usp=sharing).

In the `Filter` Sheet I used the following `FILTER()` function to retrieve some data from the `Data` Sheet.

`FILTER({Data!B12:H}, Data!B12:B<>"")`

Using the above function I'd like to add a column to the end of the retrieved data containing a value (`Lorem Ipsum`) in cell `A1` of the `Data` Sheet.

I have tried using the following filter function

`FILTER({Data!B12:H,"" &INDEX(Data!A1)}, Data!B12:B<>"")`

which yields the error

`Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 27. Actual: 1.`

My expected output is:
[image]

Please Advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=FILTER({Data!B12:H, IF(LEN(Data!B12:B), Data!A1,)}, Data!B12:B<>"")
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Works Great! Would you mind explaining your answer a bit, so I can accept it

Comment: The {} creates an array with the data in B12:H and one extra column. That extra column is constructed with the formula IF(LEN(Data!B12:B), Data!A1,). It creates the value of Data!A1 for every row that has a value in Data!B12:B.

Comment: Similar but this is what worked for me `=FILTER({'SHEET_NAME'!A2:E,IF(ROW('SHEET_NAME'!A2:A),"SHEET_NAME")},'SHEET_NAME'!A2:A<>"")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in cell `A5` on the filter sheet:

`=arrayformula(FILTER({Data!B12:H,if(Data!B12:B<>"",Data!A1,)}, Data!B12:B<>""))`

Comment: Works! but I have to use the value in cell A1

Comment: OK in that case, replace `"Lorum Ipsum"` with `Data!A1`